# How can I apply an existing CSS class style to a dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, html

Apologies for this seemingly redundant question, but the others all seem to be asking about different cases, such as using JQuery. I'm trying to dynamically create a div & apply an existing CSS style to it, but the div isn't taking on the style. Any tips are much appreciated:

```
    <style>
        div.tile {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            background:  rgba(1,1,0,1);
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
        }
        .a { left: 2cm; top: 2cm; z-index: 1; }
        .b { left: 4cm; top: 4cm; z-index: 2; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        createLayer(1);

        function createLayer(layerIndex){
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = "div"+layerIndex;
            div.class = "tile a";
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.id     = "layer" + layerIndex;
            div.appendChild(canvas);
        }
```

Comment: Css are applied to dynamically added elements

Comment: Perhaps using cenimetres instead of pixels is the issue here.

Comment: make sure that your new div is correctly generated by using an object inspector like firebug, then you may find the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In vanilla JS the property for adding a class to an element is `className` not `class`.

Try this instead:

`div.className = "tile a";`

Comment: Thanks for the help! You've also given me clues as to what keywords I should search to read up on this..

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is inspect the HTML after your function has run to make sure that the class is being applied properly.  The CSS will apply to the matching element even if it is dynamically created - unless the element isn't being tagged correctly.  I suggest using Firebug in Firefox to make sure that your div is correct.

Comment: The OP knows the CSS classes aren't being applied, that's not the issue. The issue is that  he's using the wrong syntax. Jamie got it.

Comment: I get that, but if he had checked for JS errors and/or checked the html output, he would have seen the problem :)

Comment: In that case your answer should've been a comment and not an answer.